# Network connections to DB not closing

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a daemon process which makes heavy use of a backend PostgreSQL database. Using netstat I can see a steady increase of network connections to the DB open in ESTABLISHED.

A memory dump shows a ton of `java.lang.ref.Finalizer`.  Also, a thread dump shows all the threads in:

```
"pool-1-thread-6" prio=10 tid=0x0000000000e4d800 nid=0x10eb waiting on condition     [0x00007f3736c5b000]
 java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c5524bf8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I suspect this is because I use a fixed thread pool Executor Service, and these threads show the Executor trying to conclude threads that have a resource to the DB open.

Here's where I call the close on my various DB resources:

```
    InitialContext ctx = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

           ... 

    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Notification n = new Notification(this,e);
            n.log();
        }
        try {
            if (ps != null) {
                ps.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Notification n = new Notification(this,e);
            n.log();
        }
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Notification n = new Notification(this,e);
            n.log();
        }
        try {
            if (ctx != null) {
                ctx.close();
            }
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            Notification n = new Notification(this,e);
            n.log();
        }
    }
```

I've spent a gross amount of time on this, but no matter what I do I can't seem to pull the thorn out of this code.

Please assist if you can.

Comment: Ended up finding the problem in some completely other and entirely forgotten part of code.  Thanks tho.

Answer (score 1):

As a first step I recommend is to use the new Automatic Resource Management feature to close your connections etc.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html